# Cómo hacer que el carousel de bootstrap sea widescreen (pantalla completa)

Tags: html, bootstrap

estoy trabajando con mi primer página web y tomé el carousel de bootstrap y traté de hacerlo widescreen pero no hay manera. Intenté de todas las maneras posibles que encontré en el sitio y nada, será algún tema en los wrappers que no logro entender, y aún así, jugando con el height:100% o width: 100% tampoco funciona. La intención es que luzca así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], tampoco he podido añadir texto dentro del carousel, y no sé si es posible.
Podrían ayudarme a resolver este problema?
Aquí va el HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testtt.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
  
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
  
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="fondo.png" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="item">
          <img src="fondo1.png" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="item">
          <img src="footer.png" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto tu pregunta al tamaño de tu carrosel? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350902/bootstrap-carousel-full-screen

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el elemento dentro de un contenedor `<div class="container">`, el cual posee los siguientes atributos:

```
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
```

Eliminando esa etiqueta conseguirás utilizar el 100% del `width`, para definir el height te recomiendo usar `100 vh`, lo que ajustará el alto a la pantalla del dispositivo.

Entonces tu código quedaría así:

```css
#myCarousel{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .other-section{
          height: 400px;
      }
      .bg-blue{
          background-color: blue;
      }
      .bg-red{
          background-color: red;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testtt.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
  
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
  
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1024/720" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
  
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1024/720" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1024/720" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">

          </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="other-section bg-blue"></div>
    <div class="other-section bg-red"></div>
</body>
</html>
```